# Process Builder Decision not going through even the Criteria is fulfilling

Tags: formula, process-builder, automation

I have a Process Builder (We change to Flow soon- but want to have all the automation to the record at one place so that it is easy to move to Flow).

***Use Case:*** When the Expected Revenue Date is moved out of this Month i need to get a Chatter post in the Group (this part is done through a Flow) . I used the below formula criteria in the Decision.

```
ExpectedRevenueDate__C  = IF( NOT(ISBLANK(ExpectedRevenueDate1, ExpectedRevenueDate1, ExpectedrevenueDate2)
```

ExpectedRevenueDate1 -- > Changes through Automation ( Value of Scheduled Installation Date)

***Problem:***
When i change the ExpectedRevenueDate1 --> PB passes the decision (true) and the chatter msg is posting.

But when i change Scheduled Installation Date -->which Changes ExpectedRevenueDate1 --> which changes the ExpectedRevenueDate__C. This is the General way of record update happens

In this case the Decision is not Passing even though the Criteria is fulfilling.

I checked debug logs and it showed the decision as False.

***Process Builder Decision Formula:***

```
AND(
  ISCHANGED([Order].ExpectedRevenueDate__c),  
  NOT(ISNULL([Order].ExpectedRevenueDate__c ) ),
  MONTH(PRIORVALUE([Order].ExpectedRevenueDate__c )) = MONTH(TODAY()) ,
  MONTH([Order].ExpectedRevenueDate__c  ) > MONTH(TODAY())  
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have a different process builder that changes ExpectedRevenueDate1, then you need to set your current process builder to use Re-evaluate Records in the Advanced Options (just like with workflow rules).  See [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.process_advanced_reevaluate.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different process builder that changes ExpectedRevenueDate1, then you need to set your current process builder to use Re-evaluate Records in the Advanced Options (just like with workflow rules).  See [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.process_advanced_reevaluate.htm&type=5)

> If you choose this option, the process can evaluate the same record up
> to five additional times in a single save operation. It might
> reevaluate the record because a process, workflow rule, or flow
> updated the record in the same save operation. When a record is
> reevaluated, the process uses the most recent values for that record.